# How to add a column to a table that uses the value of another row with a specific date and has the same name as the row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel I have the following situation. I have a table that has a date column, a duration column and a name column. In another cell on the sheet, I have specified a date (In the example screenshot K3). I want to add a column that gets filled with the duration of the row that has the same Name but with the date in cell K3. In the example screenshot, I have added the expected results I would like in column G.
The table also changes to have more dates or more different names so if possible, the formula should be able to adapt to this.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT([Duration]*([Date]=$K$3)*([Name]=[@Name]))
```

It will return 0 if there is no entry for a certain name and the specified Date.

[image]